# Rails 2.2.2 to Rails 3 - Sortable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am migrating an old Rails 2.2.2 project to Rails 3 and I have been fixing things along the way - The latest is below.

```
undefined method `sortable'
```

Apparently Rails 2.2.2 had a method or keyword called "sortable"? Is that part of the Rails 2.2.2 framework?

Does the same functionality exist in Rails 3?

How do I change this over to work in Rails 3?

Thanks

```
<tr>
            <th style="padding-left:20px;"><%= sortable "name", "Name" %></th>
            <th><%= sortable "company", "Company" %></th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th><%= sortable "created_at", "Created On" %></th>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the handles_sortable_columns gem, [here is](https://github.com/dadooda/handles_sortable_columns) how to setup this gem for Rails 3

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out and let you know. There is nothing in environment.rb (and I cannot find a Gemfile) that suggests this. Should I be looking someplace else?

Comment: Take a look on the vendor/plugins folder

Comment: Nothing like that in vendor/plugins either